# separating columns CSV in python

Tags: python

how to separate this line, I need just the numbers

```
PD-1358 393;
```

I would like to increment a variable X and a Y

```
 X   Y
PD-1358 393;
```

I am using the CSV command `(csv_file, delimiter='-')`
but I can not separate these numbers.
Can anybody help me?

```
import csv

with open('circulo.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='-')

    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:

         print(f'\t {row[0]}')
```

For the moment I've only been able to separate this part

Comment: please post your code as well

Comment: It is not quite clear the expected output and input. Also as mentioned above, please post the code you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression?oldformat=true) you can simply do:

```py
import re

re.findall(r'\d+', "PD-1358 393")
```

Result:

```py
['1358', '393']
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of an easy way to do this, but assuming you've turned the data into a string like so:

`s = 'PD-1358 393'`

Then create a generator to go to the first instance of a digit:

`i = next((index for (index,value) in enumerate(s) if value.isdigit()))`

And then split:

`s[i:].split()`

Returns:

`['1358', '393']`

Answer (score 0):

If you want numbers in the final array:

```
line = 'PD-1358 393;'

parts = line.split(' ')

numbers = [int(''.join(i for i in part if i.isdigit())) for part in parts]
```